# Getting complete address information from OSM without Geocoder

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, address, nominatim

I know a question like this is asked very often. But the answers did never really satisfy me.

I want to extract addresses and maybe POIs from OSM. Nothing more. I am not interested any additional information.

So I inspected some OSM raw data and found the "addr:*" tags. They seem to be a solution for my problem. But in the data I inspected the "addr:state" tag is missing at nearly every point or polygon (at least in the Berlin map I downloaded from Geofabrik).

Is there any (relatively none complex) way or possibility to get these information too from the data without doing geocoding. Or is geocoding the only possibility to solve my problem.

I know that there are mighty tools like Nominatim, that would solve the problem. But I would be happier if there was a more simple way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no simpler way.

Many POIs only contain partly [address](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Addresses) information like street name and house number but lack other address information such as city, municipality, state or country. This is perfectly fine from a data point of view since this data can be obtained by looking at [administrative boundaries](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative) covering these information. However it makes it impossible to obtain complete address information by looking just at a single POI.

Comment: Hello oele, if you can read German, then maybe have a look the web service http://regio-osm.de/ ... this offers many statistical information and quality control for address data in Germany ons some countries around ... get in contact with the maintainer of that service or ask at the German subforum at http://forum.osm.org

Comment: Hi Stephan. Thx for the hint!